# Avoiding cursor change over dynamic text fields in Flash CS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield, cs3

I have a dynamic text field inside a MovieClip symbol. Whenever the mouse pointer is hovered over the symbol, the cursor changes to the I-shaped text editing cursor. This may be a very stupid question, but is there any way to avoid this? Not even using `mouse.hide()` keeps the "I" cursor from appearing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting the TextField's selectable property to false?  This will prevent the user from dragging the mouse to select the text (thus they can't copy it to the clipboard), but I believe that should also prevent the cursor from changing.

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it had to be something like that, I just couldn't find it. Now I can go watch Mythbusters :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help someone at such a worth cause as watching Mythbusters!

Answer (score 2):

mc.selectable = false;

Answer (score 0):

For CS4: In the properties box is an icon(little button) that is available when you have the text field selected, which you can toggle on and off to determine if the text is selectable.  This button is located below anti-alias in the properties box.