# Custom cursor with mouse_down in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, custom-cursor

I want to get the a different cursor to show up for my custom cursor and this is the code I have so far. I've created the function but I am not sure where to go from here.

Ideally I would like to switch one cursor our for another, or use a different frame within the cursor's timeline. Please help if you can.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var myCursor:Sprite;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

function init()
    {
        Mouse.hide();


        myCursor = new CursorClass();
        myCursor.mouseEnabled = false;
        myCursor.visible = false;


        addChild(myCursor);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
    }

    function mouseMoveHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        myCursor.visible = true;
        myCursor.x = evt.stageX;
        myCursor.y = evt.stageY;
    }

    function mouseDownHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {

    }

    function mouseLeaveHandler(evt:Event):void
    {
        myCursor.visible = false;
    }

init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If myCursor have timeline with different shape for cursor than in mouseDownHandler set myCursor.gotoAndStop(2). 
Else you can change myCursor with instance of some MovieClip from library.

Comment: I am getting this error
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 3', Frame 25, Line 68 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

This topic looks like :

[Flex 3: How can I change the Mouse Cursor when mousing over a Text Input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778735/flex-3-how-can-i-change-the-mouse-cursor-when-mousing-over-a-text-input)

Perhaps it will help you...

Comment: I want to use a movieclip for the mouse however - not something that is built into flash