# add static text to a movie clip in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

i want to add static text in a movie clip with as3. so that text can not show the cursor over it always show pointer. I just want to add text graphic with any recommended way.

also want change font, size, color and text  as well.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587252/avoiding-cursor-change-over-dynamic-text-fields-in-flash-cs3

Comment: Thanks. let me use i will update @Cherniv

Answer (score 1):

Use the TextField class to add a new textfield into the target movieclip. Then use the TextFormat class to create a style for your text. Make sure you apply your textformat before you add textField to the display list.